# Very weird thing in IE8.. Defined variable is recognized as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

A very weird problem occurred, when I was trying to enable a lib (Beard.js) to support the javascript template engine Haml.

Haml could not be loaded correctly. I tracked down the code and find out that Haml has never been loaded into the page. After a lot of try and fail, I happened to make it work. The weird thing I found is:

in origin Haml lib, it is:

```
var Haml;

(function(){
    ...

    Haml = function(){ ... }

    ...
}());
```

I changed the code to :

```
var Haml;

(function(){
    ...

    window.Haml = function(){ ... }

    ...
}());
```

then it works..

WHY??? Shouldn't Haml be automatically recognized as defined in the global scope?

Environment - IE8
Haml.js - https://github.com/creationix/haml-js
Bear.js - https://github.com/jspopisno1/Beard

-------------- UPDATE ---------------

in Haml.js, it is:

```
var Haml;

(function(){
    ...

    Haml = function Haml(){ ... }

    ...
}());
```

I guess in the javascript, the statement "function Haml(){}" makes Haml a local var. However, why can Haml be loaded correctly in Firefox & Chrome????

Comment: IE8 is stupid....

Comment: Just speaking the truth.

Comment: @Mahnax - what is your explanation for why IE 8 is different to other browsers and how it is inconsistent with ECMA-262? If you don't have one, how do you know that it's not the other browsers that are "stupid"?

Comment: @RobG give you one http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/09/09/inconsistent-array-literals/

Comment: @RobG I use both IE8 and Safari 5 daily. Not only does Safari perform better in every way, it also looks nicer.

Comment: @LiangliangZheng - what does IE's (well known) bug with array elisions have to do with named function expressions? --Mahnax - so you have nothing. I'm no fan of IE, but deriding it without any logical reason is pointless when the OP has asked a specific technical question.

Comment: I think Mahnax was just expressing his feeling and I rationally get your point as well, but coder's human too. I think occasional yell is totally fine, after fixing tons of issues caused by incompatibility of IE and other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> var Haml;
> (function(){
>     ...
>     Haml = function Haml(){ ... }
>     ... 
> }());
```

That code does not throw any errors in IE 8 for me. The part you are missing in your question is a following statement:

```
alert(typeof Haml);
```

which shows *undefined* in IE and *function* in Firefox and others.

The assignment to *Haml* is a *named function expression* (the name is optional) and yes, IE will create a variable in the current scope with the name, other browsers don't.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to JScript (in versions up until IE8) having a bug whereby **named function expressions** leak into the enclosing scope. So named function expressions are parsed as function declarations (as well as function expressions), thereby automatically hoisting a local `Haml` variable into the local scope. After that, you set `Haml = function(){}` but that doesn't result in the global `Haml` because JScript finds a *local* variable with that identifier because it incorrectly leaked into the local scope. So while the local `Haml` is set correctly, the global one is never reached.

You can read about this more [here](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't Haml be automatically recognized as defined in the global scope?

Only if that code itself is in the global scope. If it is part of a function, the `var` will scope it to that function only.

Comment: I know. the thing is 'var Haml' is in the global scope. and i think Haml in 'Haml = blah blah' should refer to the global 'Haml', but the truth is I need to declare window.Haml explicitly. That's what confuse me.

Comment: well.. I think I found the problem.. but still confused